# Laravel scope - pass 2 parameters to scope

Tags: php, laravel, scope

I have a status column in my table with 3 states (register, forwarded, done).

I have a different links in my view for filter the results:

```
<li>{{ link_to_route('psa.index', 'Eingetragen', array('f' => 'register'), $attributes = array('title' => 'Eingetragen!' )) }}</li>
<li>{{ link_to_route('psa.index', 'Wird erledigt', array('f' => 'forwarded'), $attributes = array('title' => 'Wird erledigt!' )) }}</li>
<li>{{ link_to_route('psa.index', 'Unerledigt', array('f' => 'forwarded', 'register'), $attributes = array('title' => 'Wird erledigt!' )) }}</li>
```

Here comes the controller snippet:

```
if(Input::get('f'))
        {
            $reports = PsaReports::filter(Input::get('f'))->with('automat', 'failure')->orderBy('incoming_day', 'desc')->orderBy('incoming_time', 'desc')->paginate(30);
        }
```

And here the scope:

```
public function scopeFilter($filter, $search)
    {
        return $filter->where('status', $search);
    }
```

With the third link above i want to scope the status register **and** forwarded. The link passes two parameters, how can i pass them to the scope?

Or is it only possible with a second scope?

many thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can add a third parameter in your scope and then do something special if that parameter is set.

**Your scope**

```
public function scopeFilter($filter, $search, $search2 = null)
{
    if ($search2 !== null) {
        return $filter->where(function($query) use ($search, search2) {
            $query->where('status', $search)->orWhere('status', $search2);
        });
    }

    return $filter->where('status', $search);
}
```

**Your controller snippet**

```
if(Input::get('f'))
{
    $reports = PsaReports::filter(Input::get('f'), Input::get('f2'))->with('automat', 'failure')->orderBy('incoming_day', 'desc')->orderBy('incoming_time', 'desc')->paginate(30);
}
```

**Your link**

```
<li>{{ link_to_route('psa.index', 'Unerledigt', array('f' => 'forwarded', 'f2' => 'register'), $attributes = array('title' => 'Wird erledigt!' )) }}</li>
```

Comment: in my laravel 7 second parameter convert to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 how can i send parameter to scope